# Using Git-Flow, Will a finished feature be integrated to another feature branch?

Tags: git, github, git-flow, git-tower

After using Git-Flow for a couple of months, I have a question maybe someone could help with...

Say there are 2 feature branches checked out locally and have been pushed to the GitHub repo but not finished. One of them is the setup of a data scheme for the application and the other is working on a single screen of the application. Up until now the screen feature has not had to use the data scheme, but now that is about to change. So...

If I finish (and therefore merge) the data-scheme-feature into the develop branch, will this code (and functionality) added to the develop branch be visible in the screen-feature.

Will I need to re-pull the screen branch? Will I have to finish the screen branch and then start a new feature in order to be able to use the newly added data-scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I need to re-pull the screen branch?

You could simply merge `develop` into the still-in-progress `screen-feature` branch. And go on in that branch, with everything available.